# Paypal IPN verification failed because character encoding

Tags: spring, paypal, spring-security, paypal-ipn, spring-boot

I have a problem with Paypal IPN verification in my Spring boot server. I'm not sure where is the problem, if at the server's side or in the other hand, it's Paypal's fault. I already selected UTF-8 as enconding in my profile page.

The main problem it's IPN with UTF-8 characters, which are making the verification fail I guess.

If I have no [CharacterEncodingFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html) in my Spring and Spring security server, IPN verification works fine. BUT makes other things (forms, for example) not showing with UTF-8 encoding, so this is an unacceptable solution.

I find strange when I'm printing the IPN (with no CharacterEnconding, so payment gets *Verified*) the response I get (among other things):

> charset=UTF-8
>
> address_name=AdriÃ¡n
>
> payment_status=Completed

So Paypal says that IPN it's UTF-8 but that's what I'm not receiving.

The server's encoding it's working fine adding CharacterEncodingFilter before Spring Security filter chain:

```
@Order(1)
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncodingFilter = servletContext
                .addFilter("characterEncodingFilter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        characterEncodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "false");
        characterEncodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
        
        insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());   
    }
}
```

And now, Paypal's IPN printing show params well encoded:

> charset=UTF-8
>
> first_name=Adrián
>
> payment_status=Completed

but Paypal's response is INVALID.

This is my Controller that handles Paypal IPN's post:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "paypalok", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void processIPN(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String PAY_PAL_DEBUG = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        String CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
        String MIME_APP_URLENC = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        String PARAM_NAME_CMD = "cmd";
        String PARAM_VAL_CMD = "_notify-validate";
        String PAYMENT_COMPLETED = "Completed";
        String paymentStatus = "";

        // Create client for Http communication
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        // Request configuration can be overridden at the request level.
        // They will take precedence over the one set at the client level.
        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setSocketTimeout(40000).setConnectTimeout(40000)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(40000).build();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(PAY_PAL_DEBUG);
        httppost.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, MIME_APP_URLENC);

        try {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PARAM_NAME_CMD, PARAM_VAL_CMD));

            // Process the parameters
            Enumeration<String> names = request.getParameterNames();
            while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
//              String param = names.nextElement();
//              String value = request.getParameter(param);
                
                String param = new String (names.nextElement().getBytes ("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                String value = new String (request.getParameter(param).getBytes ("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8");

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(param, value));
                params.put(param, value);
                System.out.println(param + "=" + value);
                // Get the payment status
                if (param.equalsIgnoreCase("payment_status")) paymentStatus = value;
            }

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            if (verifyResponse(httpClient.execute(httppost))) {
                // if (paymentStatus.equalsIgnoreCase(PAYMENT_COMPLETED)) do...
                return "elovendo/pricing/paymentOk";
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "redirect:/error";
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "redirect:/error";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "redirect:/error";
        }
    }

    private boolean verifyResponse(HttpResponse response) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {

        String RESP_VERIFIED = "VERIFIED";

        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String responseText = reader.readLine();
        is.close();

        System.out.println("RESPONSE : " + responseText);

        return responseText.equals(RESP_VERIFIED);

    }
```

I have uri encoding with:

```
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfiguration {

    /** HTTPS and Paging error **/
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.setUriEncoding("UTF-8");
    }
}
```

**Resuming**, if I send the characters UTF-8 encoded Paypal verification fails, even when it shouldn't come *bad-encoded*. If I send them *bad-encoded*, Paypal's response it's ok.

I can't send the IPN's response *bad-encoded* using CharacterEncodingFilter, can't I?

I'm don't really know what's going on.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I actually don't know why Paypal is sending data wrong encoded, but a simply workaround manages that.

Just overriding CharacterEncodingFilter like this:

```
public class CharacterEncodingFilter extends org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request != null && !request.getRequestURI().contains("paypalcheck")) {
            super.doFilterInternal(request, response, filterChain);
        }
        else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }
}
```

making reference to the controller URL that listens the Paypal's IPN and telling the Filter that don't encode the data.

And also, making sure that the filter is before Spring Security chain:

```
public class SecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        filter.setForceEncoding(true);
        http.addFilterBefore(filter, WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.class);
    }
}
```